# Run Dart SDK self-test suite of the pre-compiled SDK

Tags: dart, unit-testing

Dart SDK sources has a unit [tests set](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/main/tests). I'd like to run it on **official pre-compiled and installed Flutter SDK** to be sure my runtime device works well.

I can't find a straight forward way to run the tests without re-build the SDK itself before. [Testing Wiki](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Testing) doesn't help too

Comment: What is your runtime device that you feel the need to do this? If your runtime device is an officially supported platform, there is no need to run the tests as they have already been run prior to that version of Flutter being published, but even ignoring that, the distributable of the Flutter SDK should include the binaries and Dart source code you need in order to run the tests. If your device is **not** an officially supported platform (like Samsung Tizen or something) then you will need to build the SDK for your platform anyway.

Comment: My runtime device is a Windows 10 based Dart VM. I want run whole test set because I found an issue and found particular unit test for the similar case. When I added the test source file in a new Dart project it failed as well. So the SDK doesn't look well-tested even on exist unit tests. See https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/51778 for details

Comment: @Abion47 - I don't see such Dart unit tests source code in the distributable of the Flutter SDK

Comment: If it's a real bug, then you did the right thing to post it as an issue on GitHub. Also, I didn't say the tests themselves are included in the distributable. I said everything you need to run the tests is included in the distributable, i.e. the source code that you would run the tests on. You should be able to import the tests from the repo into the distribution install directory and then follow the instructions from the testing wiki to run the tests.